# Adding labels to a Webform multistep form

Tags: webforms

I have a form with 3 steps using the Webform module. Is there a way for me to identify what step I'm in so I can style it separately? What I'm after is to place text like *Step 1 > Step 2 > Step 3* while highlighting the current step using CSS.

So far, I can't find any ID or class which tells me what step I'm in.

**EDIT**: Not that important but any suggestions on how I can place the text *Step 1 > Step 2 > Step 3?* I was thinking of adding the text in `body` but maybe there's another/better way? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a fieldset around each step with the labels "step 1-3"

Comment: Oohhh, I feel so stupid...very, very stupid. :p

Comment: it's ok. sometimes we can't see the forest for the trees when working on a project. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use variable_set to track your current step # and add increments as you go along...

`if(variable_get('stepno')){`

```
variable_set('stepno',variable_get('stepno')+1);
drupal_set_message('step: '.variable_get('stepno'));
```

} else {
    variable_set('stepno',1);
    drupal_set_message('Step 1');
}

Answer (score 0):

At the edit side, you can rename the page break also, to keep track in the admin side what step you're editing — I'm using webforms 4 here.